# How to apply Google Analytics to custom made buttons for social sharing on the site using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter, google-analytics, linkedin-api

I want to track the analytics (using Google Analytics), for how many shares have been done from my page to Google+, Twitter, LinkedIn and Pinterest using the custom made buttons of them on my site.

But, I was unable to find the APIs for the same.

I did it for FB using the following code:

```
FB.ui(
    {
            method: 'share',
            href: location.href,
    },
    function(response) {
        if (response && response.post_id) {
            ga('send', {
                'hitType' : 'social',
                'socialNetwork' : 'Facebook',
                'socialAction' : 'Share',
                'socialTarget' : location.href,
                'page' : location.pathname
            });
        }
})
```

Answer (score 3):

Please take a look to how [Komito Analytics](https://komito.net/) does. See functions in the [source code](https://github.com/Datamart/Komito/tree/master/src/komito/trackers/social).

Comment: Facebook API: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe